# Using ranked model with rails 4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-4

I’ve been using [ranked model](https://github.com/mixonic/ranked-model) and following along with this [sortable tables tutorial](http://benw.me/posts/sortable-bootstrap-tables/).

I’m pulling my hair out over this, and anything anyone can do to help would be fantastic!

I’ve got `Decks` which has_many `Cards`. And on the decks edit page, I’m trying to sort its own set of cards.

**card.rb**

```
belongs_to :deck
include RankedModel
ranks :row_order, :with_same => :deck_id
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :decks do 
  post :sort, on: :collection
  resources :cards
end
```

**decks_controller.rb**

```
def sort
  @deck = Deck.find(params[:id])
  @deck.update_attributes(deck_params)
  @deck.save
  render nothing: true
end

def deck_params
  params.require(:deck).permit(:name, :id, :cards_attributes => [:id, :question, :answer, :deck_id, :_destroy, :row_order, :row_order_position])
end
```

**jquery**

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: $(this).data('update_url'),
  dataType: 'json',
  data: { id: deck_id, deck: { cards_attributes: { row_order_position: position } }}
```

This is all on Rails 4.
I think the problem is how I’m posting the data.

I’ve checked `row_order` on the cards themselves, and it's being set. I just can’t seem to understand how to pass the information via ajax with the nested `cards_attributes`.

I'm also unsure why the tutorial shows `row_order_position: position` in the ajax post, when I thought it would just be `row_order: position`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things here (I was going to write a comment, but it will be easier to read as an answer):

---

**Does It Work Like You Want?**

I looked over your code, and it seems like you're trying to just change the `position` of the deck, with no callback in your ajax

Is this how you want it to work? Personally, I'd make a separate model called `DeckPosition`, which you can use like this:

```
#app/models/deck_position.rb
Class DeckPosition < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :deck, :class_name => 'Deck'
    belongs_to :card, :class_name => 'Card'
end

#app/models/deck.rb
Class Deck < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :card_positions, :class_name => 'DeckPosition'
    has_many :cards, :class_name => 'Card', :through => :card_positions

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :cards
end

#app/models/card.rb
Class Card < ActiveRecord::Base 
    has_many :deck_positions, :class_name => 'DeckPosition'
    has_many :decks, :class_name => 'Deck', :through => :deck_positions
end
```

I'd then include the attribute "order" in the join model:

```
deck_positions table
id | deck_id | card_id | row_order_position | created_at | updated_at
```

This could be completely wrong, but judging from your questions, it seems like it's something you could benefit from

---

**Nested Attributes**

You seem to be passing nested attributes to your cards model, and yet you've not got any reference to this in your code? I have added the applicable code to the `Deck` model, in my own code; so maybe you would want to look at that?

---

**Sorting**

One of the reasons why I asked about your Ajax was that you're sending a request to your server, but don't seem to be handling it? This is important because although I've not used the ranking gem before, it seems you want to be able to sort some important aspects of your application? How do you want them to be handled?